# Meteor Js Will not let me download a file from server

Tags: javascript, file, meteor, download, file-permissions

Is there a way that I can trigger a file to download from the public folder?

I have a button that goes and gets the file from another server and stores it in the downloaded folder. I can confirm this works.
Then I want that file to be downloaded to the clients pc.

I just want a line of code that will trigger it.
**window.location.assign(fileLocation);** gives me the error:

Not allowed to load local resource:     **file:///D:/Dev/Projects/Downloader/.meteor/.downloaded/Late%20For%20Work.mp3**

I have also tried with the path and file being      **file:///D:/Dev/Projects/Downloader/public/.downloaded/Late%20For%20Work.mp3**

Comment: You shouldn't be operating within the `.meteor` folder.  That folder is strictly for your app to maintain compile/build/etc related files and folders.  The place you want to use is `/public`.  There you should be able to simple use an anchor tag with the href of `/public/<path>/<filename>`.

Answer (score 0):

fire up your server and navigato to

```
localhost:port {or any host}/.downloaded/file.xyz
```

if you are trying to add the file in the public folder dont do that once the public folder is changed the app refreshes

Comment: I know the app refreshes but where else should I store the file so that the user can download it?

Comment: use CollectionFs or any File hosting service like  AWS